# Get "My Documents" File in Android

Tags: java, android

I've got a couple of voice recordings and I'd like to play them from my code simply by telling the MediaPlayer the file to play.

Trouble is I can't find the files! The phone claims they are in "My Documents/My Recordings", as does windows when I connect the phone as a disk. But when I open that folder as a File in Java, it isn't there.

I've looked at `Android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, but I haven't found the magic incantation to get to **My Documents**.

Any help would be much appreciated!

< Edit >
Found the files in `/sdcard/My Documents/My Recordings` - so I guess the questions becomes "is there a more portable way of doing it than just hard coding /sdcard?".

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

This is [described here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a `DIRECTORY_RECORDINGS`...

Looking at your specific problem, the text suggests that `getExternalStorageDirectory()` would return `My Documents` on Android 4.2. Perhaps try this hack:

```
String myDocs = new Path(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)).getParent();
```

Comment: Thanks - good idea to get part of the path via a different file type, so I've upped it, but it isnt really a full answer (but it is certainly better than my solution of hardcoding!).